# Pass values + upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, telerik

I am using asp.net c# and Telerik tools. My question is, I am tring to pass the values

of (textbox, drop down list and file uploaded details) to another asp page using java script, however nothing work and I want to get the file content and pass it as well ?? can you give me a solution? please!

on page1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               function GetRadWindow() {
                    var oWindow = null;
                    if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
                    else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
                    return oWindow;
               }
               function populateCityName(arg) {
                   var cityName = document.getElementById("cityName");
                   cityName.value = arg;
               }
                function returnToParent() {
                    //create the argument that will be returned to the parent page
                    var oArg = new Object();

                    //get the city's name           
                    oArg.cityName = document.getElementById("cityName").value;
                    //get a reference to the current RadWindow
                    var oWnd = GetRadWindow();




                    //Close the RadWindow and send the argument to the parent page
                    if (oArg.cityName) {
                        oWnd.close(oArg);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Please fill field");
                    }
                }
          </script>
```

page 2:

```
 function OnClientClose(oWnd, args) {
                //get the transferred arguments
                var arg = args.get_argument();
                if (arg) {
                    var cityName = arg.cityName;

            $get("order").innerHTML = "You chose to fly to <strong>" + cityName + "</strong>";
                }
```

Comment: What won't work? What have you tried?

Comment: first I tried to pass the textbox values as shown below but I faild 
                   var cityName = document.getElementById("cityName");
                   cityName.value = arg;

Comment: Also I tried to get the file content as string to save it database but I don't how to do it?

Comment: @user2349354 update question with relevant code that explain what have you tried.

Comment: I update the questions with the code @user2349354

Answer (score 1):

Try using
 `var cityName = document.getElementById('<%= cityName.ClientID %>');` instead of

```
var cityName = document.getElementById("cityName");
```

Comment: First check if the names are changed in html due to telerik tools for that select inspect element in your browswer . Then use the id name used that html code

Comment: How you are passing javascript variables from one page to other?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Session variable to store uploaded fileContent and access it on another page.

For simple text like value of a TextBox or a dropdown, you can directly send them through querystring.

Create a Session Variable like this.

**page1.aspx.cs**

```
Session["FileContent"] = FileUpload1.FileContent;
```

and access it on another page like below;

**page2.aspx.cs**

```
if(Session["FileContent"]!=null)
{
    Stream fileData = (Stream)Session["FileContent"];

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string imgData = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //save imgData to db
}
```

**you cannot access other pages control value through javascript.**
if you don't get anything by doing this `document.getElementById("cityName")`, then that simply means, no such control with the id exist on this page.

Try passing TextBox text using queryString (or Session variable).

Comment: I am using telerik upload tools so [FileUpload1.FileContent;] it wont work with it

Comment: so what? telerik tools must have provided even easier way to get the file content. the answer intends to show how you can transfer selected file data from one page to another.

Comment: I will try using querystring .. and for telerik i will try again that method, thanks for helping in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are Telerik-specific APIs that will help you with passing data from the RadWindow to a parent window, and you can reload the uploaded file content using the AjaxManager.

Consider this sample that demonstrates how to pass values back from the RadWindow to the owning page:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/clientsideevents/defaultcs.aspx?product=window